# Symfony project inheritance and sfguard

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4, sfguard

is this a right syntaxe of my Schema.yml ??

```
  user_type_1 :
    inheritance:
    type:             concrete
    extends:          sfGuardUser
 columns:
   name: { type: string(255) }

  user_type_2 :
    inheritance:
    type:             concrete
    extends:          sfGuardUser
 columns:
   name: { type: string(255) }
```

My project consiste of two type of users **user_type_1** and **user_type_2** and i want both of them to inheritance from sfGuardUser ,shoud i use inheritance type **concrete** or **column_aggregation**

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either one, it depends on what you want.
From the [docs](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine/en/latest/en/manual/inheritance.html):

**Concrete** 
Concrete inheritance creates separate tables for child classes. However in concrete inheritance each class generates a table which contains all columns (including inherited columns). In order to use concrete inheritance you’ll need to add explicit parent::setTableDefinition() calls to child classes as shown below.

**Column Aggregation**
In the following example we have one database table called entity. Users and groups are both entities and they share the same database table.
The entity table has a column called type which tells whether an entity is a group or a user. Then we decide that users are type 1 and groups type 2.
The only thing we have to do is to create 3 records (the same as before) and add the call to the Doctrine_Table::setSubclasses() method from the parent class.

Using concrete inheritance will create 2 tables (user_type_1 and user_type_2), and column_aggregation will only create 1 table with a 'type' column.